# Remove macOS app from sale, but keep iOS app

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect

[Appstore Connect with iOS and macOS app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JZmD.png)

We have an app in AppStoreConnect which has both a native iOS and a native macOS app.  Need to remove the macOS app only, but keep the iOS app available and on sale.

If I tweak which countries the macOS app is available in, this seems to be reflected in the iOS app as well, which makes me think if I hit "Remove from sale" both iOS and macOS will get pulled from the store, which is not the desired outcome.

Anyone know how to remove the macOS app, but keep the iOS one?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution???? I still try to remove the macOS app

Comment: Any findings @Mc.Lover?

Comment: @hyouuu Unfortuntely no!! once you did there is no way to remove the macOS target, and this is so so ridiculous

Comment: Aw @Mc.Lover so basically the app gets stuck with the developer account forever unless you delete it? 

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem and don't want to support macOS any longer. I posted another question with the ideas I came up with so far (which are both not practical) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77802918/app-store-connect-remove-submitted-macos-app-but-keep-ios-app